# React Native App Stuck on Loading Screen When Trying to Retrieve Videos from MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, expo, gridfs

I'm working on a simple social media app using React Native with the Expo toolchain. The main functionality of the app is to allow users to upload videos and share them with others. On the "Explore" screen, users should be able to view the uploaded videos. The videos are retrieved from a MongoDB Atlas database and are expected to be displayed in the app. However, I'm stuck with a loading icon when I load the app, and it eventually times out.

Here are some details of my setup:

The video upload and retrieval functionality is handled by an Express.js backend server.
I use the Multer middleware for handling multipart/form-data and the multer-gridfs-storage engine to store uploaded files directly to MongoDB using the GridFS specification.
I am able to successfully upload videos from my phone, and they appear as new collections in the MongoDB database (inside the 'test' database, in collections named 'uploads.files.chunks' and 'uploads.files.files').
I can load static text from my server (the "Hello World!" message), but the video retrieval is not working.

I have tried a number of things to diagnose the problem, including:

Verifying that my server is running and connected to MongoDB
Ensuring that my '/api/videos' route is being hit by placing console logs
Checking the database to see if the files exist (they do)
Checking for network requests in the browser developer tools (none appear)

Below is the relevant code from my Express.js server:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const { GridFsStorage } = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

// Create Express server
const app = express();

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Database connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

conn.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

conn.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB', err);
});

let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Initialize GridFS
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads.files');

  // Add this test query
  conn.db.collection('uploads.files').find().limit(1).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log('Test Query executed');
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error executing test query', err);
    } else if (docs.length === 0) {
      console.log('Test query returned no documents');
    } else {
      console.log('Test query returned document:', docs[0]);
    }
  });

  // Start server
  const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  });
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  options: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Use the _id as the filename
      const filename = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
      const fileInfo = {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: 'uploads.files',
      };
      resolve(fileInfo);
    });
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/api/videos', upload.single('video'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('Upload route hit'); 
  console.log('req.body:', req.body);
  console.log('req.file:', req.file);
  // Video uploaded successfully
  res.json({ message: 'Video uploaded successfully' });
});

app.get('/api/videos', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Get videos route hit');
  gfs.files.find().sort({ uploadDate: -1 }).toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if an error occurred during the database query
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred during database query:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
    
    // Check if files exist
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No files exist');
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No files exist' });
    }

    // Files exist
    console.log('Files found:', files);
    return res.json(files);
  }).catch(err => console.error('Error executing query:', err));  // Add this line
});
```

And here is the relevant code from my front-end React Native app:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import VideoPlayer from '../components/VideoPlayer';

function Explore() {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVideos = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/videos');
        console.log('Response data:', response.data); // Add this line
        setVideos(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);  // Add this line
        setError(err.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
  
    fetchVideos();
  }, []);
  

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.errorText}>Error: {error}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {videos.length > 0 ? (
  videos.map(video => (
    <VideoPlayer key={video._id} videoId={video._id} />  // Replace _id with filename if necessary
  ))
) : (
  <Text>No videos found.</Text>
)}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  errorContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  errorText: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default Explore;
```

When I attempt to load the Explore screen, I only see "Get video route hit" in my terminal and nothing else. The screen continues to show the loading icon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm unsure of how to proceed from here. Even ChatGPT hit me with a "Sorry, I can't figure this out" lol.

Comment: Are there slow queries shown in the Profiler of the Atlas UI (or in the log files when you download them)? Is there an index on the field that you are sorting on? Do you really want to pull everything back and load it into application memory all at once? Does changing the find and sort to either a findOne or a find and limit(1) come back successfully?

Comment: Which `console.log` messages are reported?

Comment: @rickhg12hs When I hit the API route, I see the "Get videos route hit" message in the server console. However, the route seems to hang and doesn't return any data or errors.

Comment: @user20042973  Thanks for your reply. As a novice, I'm not very familiar with the Profiler in Atlas UI or how to check for slow queries. As for indexing, I have not manually created any indexes, so if there are any, they would be the default ones MongoDB creates. I'm sorting on the uploadDate field when retrieving videos. Would it help to create an index on this field? I'm currently pulling all videos at once, but this is mostly due to my limited knowledge. If there's a more efficient way to do this, I'm open to suggestions! When I limit my query to find only one document, it does return

Comment: Yes, creating an index on `uploadDate: -1` should help.  So we have a sense of scale, how many videos are there?  When you do limit your query to one document, does everything, taking the limitation into consideration, work correctly?

Comment: I agree that the index will help and should be created. But yeah that's probably not the full solution. Streaming the entire data set back to the client is probably not the correct approach. Instead should use a cursor with the appropriately sized batch. Namely don't `.toArray()` the entire result set as that forces materialization. The specifics of what changes to make to the code depend a bit on what overall approach you go with. Related: look into keyset pagination as potentially helpful here

Comment: @rickhg12hs There's only one video at the moment as I'm in the early stages of building the application, but I aim to scale it to accommodate any number of videos that users may upload in the future.
I have tried limiting the query to one document and I'm still seeing the same behavior where the query seems to hang and not return any data or errors. When I hit the API route, I see the 'Get videos route hit' message in my server console, which indicates that the server is receiving the request correctly, but I don't see any further console messages after that.

Comment: @user20042973 Much appreciated! I'll definitely look into how to implement this in my code.
Regarding creating an index, I will follow your advice and create one on the uploadDate field. I will also look into the Atlas UI Profiler and try to understand if there are any slow queries.

As I'm still learning, your suggestions are very valuable. If you have any resources or examples you think would be helpful for me, I would appreciate it.